# Android: looking for a drawArc() method with inner & outer radius

Tags: android, 2d, draw, geometric-arc

I have the following custom view:

[image]

This I have achieved by using the Canvas' `drawArc()` method. However, with this `drawArc()` method I cannot limit the arc's inner radius.

What I'd like to have is something like this:

[image]

where there is only an outer ring left.

What I need is an `drawArc()` function where I can set the inner radius of the arc. Anyone an idea how to do that?

(BTW, overpainting the inner area doesn't work, because it needs to be transparent. Painting an inner circle with `Color.TRANSPARENT` after painting the red and blue cones doesn't remove the old color. It just puts another layer on top, which is transparent and through which I can still see the red and blue)

Comment: Can you post your latest code after got your final requirement? Thanks

Comment: Does any one know how to make smooth edges of meeting angles, as In my case when I am making ring with 4-5 equal distribution and different colors I can see background at the edges

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can paint over the inner area using the PorterDuff xfermode called "Clear." This will erase pixels.

Comment: That's a possible solution. But what to do for the case, that there's already something drawn in the inner circle, which I don't want to get overpainted and neither to I want to erase the pixels and redraw it?

Comment: Draw the circle in an offscreen ARGB8888 bitmap, do the clear there, then draw the bitmap onto your Canvas. And that way you also don't have to redraw the circle every time.

Comment: So, after looking into how to actually do this, I'm a bit lost: is an ARGB8888 bitmap a "normal" Bitmap http://goo.gl/ygTn - and how do I get the same drawing functions as I do with Canvas?

Comment: Update: I figured out that I can actually do it this way

Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);

and then draw on the Canvas, which will then write the actual pixels on the Bitmap.

Answer (score 76):

You can do this:

```
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    final RectF rect = new RectF();
    //Example values
    rect.set(mWidth/2- mRadius, mHeight/2 - mRadius, mWidth/2 + mRadius, mHeight/2 + mRadius); 
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    canvas.drawArc(rect, -90, 360, false, paint);
```

The key is in `paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);`, it crops the arc's center with the stroke that you define in setStrokeWidth (in the example draws an arc with a radius of mRadius and 20px thick).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Works like a charm! Sometimes I forget to subtract the stroke from the container and I get a cropped circle. Thanks.

Comment: And if you use `paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);` instead of `paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);` you get exactly what the question want.

Comment: I think you can safely use `canvas.drawArc(rect,0,360,false,paint);` instead of -90

Comment: Can you set a Gradient color (like shader) to this?

Comment: `Paint.Cap.BUTT` is the default, so you might as well just delete the `paint.setStrokeCap();` line.

Answer (score 20):

```
private static final float CIRCLE_LIMIT = 359.9999f;
/**
 * Draws a thick arc between the defined angles, see {@link Canvas#drawArc} for more.
 * This method is equivalent to
 * <pre><code>
 * float rMid = (rInn + rOut) / 2;
 * paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE); // there's nothing to fill
 * paint.setStrokeWidth(rOut - rInn); // thickness
 * canvas.drawArc(new RectF(cx - rMid, cy - rMid, cx + rMid, cy + rMid), startAngle, sweepAngle, false, paint);
 * </code></pre>
 * but supports different fill and stroke paints.
 * 
 * @param canvas
 * @param cx horizontal middle point of the oval
 * @param cy vertical middle point of the oval
 * @param rInn inner radius of the arc segment
 * @param rOut outer radius of the arc segment
 * @param startAngle see {@link Canvas#drawArc}
 * @param sweepAngle see {@link Canvas#drawArc}, capped at &plusmn;360
 * @param fill filling paint, can be <code>null</code>
 * @param stroke stroke paint, can be <code>null</code>
 * @see Canvas#drawArc
 */
public static void drawArcSegment(Canvas canvas, float cx, float cy, float rInn, float rOut, float startAngle,
        float sweepAngle, Paint fill, Paint stroke) {
    if (sweepAngle > CIRCLE_LIMIT) {
        sweepAngle = CIRCLE_LIMIT;
    }
    if (sweepAngle < -CIRCLE_LIMIT) {
        sweepAngle = -CIRCLE_LIMIT;
    }

    RectF outerRect = new RectF(cx - rOut, cy - rOut, cx + rOut, cy + rOut);
    RectF innerRect = new RectF(cx - rInn, cy - rInn, cx + rInn, cy + rInn);

    Path segmentPath = new Path();
    double start = toRadians(startAngle);
    segmentPath.moveTo((float)(cx + rInn * cos(start)), (float)(cy + rInn * sin(start)));
    segmentPath.lineTo((float)(cx + rOut * cos(start)), (float)(cy + rOut * sin(start)));
    segmentPath.arcTo(outerRect, startAngle, sweepAngle);
    double end = toRadians(startAngle + sweepAngle);
    segmentPath.lineTo((float)(cx + rInn * cos(end)), (float)(cy + rInn * sin(end)));
    segmentPath.arcTo(innerRect, startAngle + sweepAngle, -sweepAngle);
    if (fill != null) {
        canvas.drawPath(segmentPath, fill);
    }
    if (stroke != null) {
        canvas.drawPath(segmentPath, stroke);
    }
}
```

Can be extended to oval arc by duplicating `rInn` and `rOut` for x and y directions.

Also wasn't part of the question, but to draw a text in the middle of a segment:

```
textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
Path midway = new Path();
float r = (rIn + rOut) / 2;
RectF segment = new RectF(cx - r, cy - r, cx + r, cy + r);
midway.addArc(segment, startAngle, sweepAngle);
canvas.drawTextOnPath("label", midway, 0, 0, textPaint);
```

Comment: this code is amazing! However I have a question, is there way I can make the lines between  the circles to have a different color than the circles perimeter color?

Comment: @Snake, you'll have to split `segmentPath.*To()` calls into multiple `Path`s and draw each separately with your select stroke colors. You can do what you discribe with 2 paths: `moveTo,lineTo,moveTo,lineTo` and `moveTo,arcTo,moveTo,arcTo`. You'll still have to keep the current one to have something to fill.

Comment: I "think" I vaguely understood it. Since I still require your help, I created another question as you suggested. Looking forward for your help. Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850634/change-the-following-code-to-include-different-colors-for-different-strokes

Comment: It is not necessary to use `lineTo`. For the second `arcTo()` add `false` as a final parameter; this will draw a line from the end of the first arc to the beginning of the second. Then `close()` the path.

Answer (score 3):

drawing Circle and Arc. the following code is little dirty but it may help

```
        int sweepAngle sweepAngle = (360/7)%360;
    int startAngle = -90;
    int x = getWidth()/2;
    int y = getHeight()/2;
    int radius;
    radius = getWidth()/2-50;
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(50);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
    mBarPaintFill.setAntiAlias(true);

    canvas.drawCircle(x , y , radius, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    for (int i = 1 ; i<=5 ; i++){

        canvas.drawArc(x-radius,y-radius,x+radius,y+radius,startAngle,sweepAngle,false,paint);
        startAngle = (startAngle + sweepAngle+20)%360;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try following ShapeDrawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval" >
        <size
            android:height="56dp"
            android:width="56dp" />

        <stroke
            android:width="10dp"
            android:color="#0000ff" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval" >
        <size
            android:height="24dp"
            android:width="25dp" />

        <stroke
            android:dashGap="10dp"
            android:dashWidth="10dp"
            android:width="10dp"
            android:color="#FF0000" />
    </shape>
</item>
```