# Circular progress bar

Tags: android

I am working on an application that needs a "circular progress bar" something like this (it doesn't need to have color changes or be empty in the middle, a simple thing would be enought for me, but if you'd like to tell me how to make color changes aswell i'll be happy to learn :) )

[image]

I want to use it to show the battery percentage in my app

Comment: Have you tried searching for such a thing? If so, what have you found?

Comment: I have not tried because i don't know where to start, i searched on stackoverflow but i found only javascript results, i don't even know what to search exactly

Comment: Hmmm, maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874424/android-looking-for-a-drawarc-method-with-inner-outer-radius

Comment: thanks, this can be useful, at least i know what to search for, now i have to find out how to use that drawArc() :)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I actually wonder how to achieve color changes...

Answer (score 2):

I hope something like [this lib](https://github.com/ylyc/circular_progress_bar/blob/master/README.md) would help

Definition in layout is simple:

```
<com.lylc.widget.circularprogressbar.example.CircularProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/circularprogressbar1"
    style="@style/Widget.ProgressBar.Holo.CircularProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="120dip"
    android:layout_height="120dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    circular:subtitle="subtitle"
    circular:title="Title" />
```

and usage is not complicated as well:

```
CircularProgressBar c3 = (CircularProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.circularprogressbar3);
c3.setTitle("June");
c3.setSubTitle("2013");
c3.setProgress(42);
```

It supports animated progress as well in case you need it. All credits to original author. I just found it. Hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if I understood you well, but I think that it can help you:
[How to change color in circular progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337613/how-to-custom-circular-progress-bar-color)

Comment: I don't think it's what i'm looking for, from what i understand this is an animation of a progress bar without a value, i need to give it a value (battery percentage) and based on the value it has to change

Answer (score 0):

use this method to and set it to image view it draw a bitmap on image view. u can use this piece of code to show a progress dialog.

```
private void circularImageBar(ImageView iv2, int i) {


    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b); 
    Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#c4c4c4"));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawCircle(150, 150, 140, paint);

        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFDB4C"));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);   
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        final RectF oval = new RectF();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        oval.set(10,10,290,290);

        canvas.drawArc(oval, 270, ((i*360)/100), false, paint);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);    
        paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#8E8E93")); 
        paint.setTextSize(140);

        canvas.drawText(""+i, 150, 150+(paint.getTextSize()/3), paint); 

        iv2.setImageBitmap(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below library

https://github.com/chillerlabs/android-circular-progress-bar

This is exactly which support complex gradient with circular progress bar