# Animate Android Ring Shape's sweep angle

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation, shapedrawable

Attempting to animate the Android Ring Shape to produce an effect similiar to the shown sequence of images.

[image: Intended Animation]

I have found the Shape Drawable type of Ring.

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="ring"
android:innerRadius="75dp"
android:thickness="25dp"
android:useLevel="false">
```

Along with the ArcShape(startAngle, sweepAngle) method.

```
ShapeDrawable shape = new ShapeDrawable(new ArcShape(0, 360));     
shape.setIntrinsicHeight(100);
shape.setIntrinsicWidth(100);
shape.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

However, the problems arise from being unable to find the drawable shape's sweep angle property or the ability to create an inner radius for ArcShape.

I am attempting to produce a smooth animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Useful material: [Android: looking for a drawArc() method with inner & outer radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874424/android-looking-for-a-drawarc-method-with-inner-outer-radius)

Using PorterDuff Clear mode the inner can be "removed", leaving a doughnut shape. You can then use the Arc's sweep angle by redrawing through extending the Animation class.

Answer (score 5):

Old thread but i think it's still useful.

I managed to get a similar behaviour using the above code:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:height="56dp"
                android:width="56dp"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="6dp"
                android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:height="50dp"
                android:width="50dp"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="6dp"
                android:dashGap="140dp"
                android:dashWidth="16dp"
                android:color="#FF0000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The key here is to play with the dashGap and dashWidth values until you get the desired image.

Answer (score 0):

### You draw a Arc shape Start angle and Sweep angle to diffrent way..you darw diifrent arc in this way ##

[See THe Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYIXC.png)

```
ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable=new ShapeDrawable(new ArcShape(220,320));
        shapeDrawable.setIntrinsicHeight(100);
        shapeDrawable.setIntrinsicWidth(100);
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
        I1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        I1.setImageDrawable(shapeDrawable);
```

Comment: while this is maybe the answer provide some explanation about your code to help questioner more ;)