# Creating a bent line like an arc in Android using xml in drawable

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, shapedrawable

**What I did**..

```
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="40"
        android:toDegrees="20"
        android:pivotX="25%"
        android:pivotY="50%" >
        <shape
            android:shape="line"
            android:top="1dip" >
            <stroke
                android:width="1dip"
                android:color="#FF0000" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

**It rotates but doesn't bend. It needs to be bent to form an arc like shape**

Any Idea?

Comment: Just wondering, have you solved this issue? I'm facinge the exat same problem! :)

Comment: I used an image instead..quick and easy..didn't try it further, if you find a solution, pls post it

Comment: I'm trying to do it programmatically, using an ArcShape

Comment: this thread might be of some help , you just need to increase the circumference, to get your desired arc shape http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013538/animate-android-ring-shapes-sweep-angle

Comment: Ok my problem was a little bit different i need to create a dark semi-trasparent slice over a circle, anyway i think that since you must do a bent it could be the same. I found a solution, it involves some programmatic changes, but nothing too hard. If you want later i will post my solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can draw a `ring` shape, rotate it based on your preference and use it with `ProgressBar` as `progressDrawable` with a set progress.

drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="150"
    android:toDegrees="150">

    <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="10dp"
        android:innerRadius="20dp"
        android:useLevel="true"><!-- this line fixes the issue for lollipop api 21 -->

        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    </shape>
</rotate>
```

layout.xml

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/widget_arc"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="67"
    />
```

You can set the progress dinamically and also easy to animate it

*Use dimen res values