# Circle Border with Different Arc Colors

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

How to make a circle border with arcs of two colors like following picture?
[image: .]

I'm using canvas and the thing which I started by creating separate arcs of different color and then combining them together like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131954/how-to-draw-arc-between-two-points-on-the-canvas).

But this greatly increases the complexity of the app. Additionally, I have to create multiple circles and rotate them frame by frame once the app starts. With so many different arcs, everything gets messy.

Is there a nicer way of doing this? Is it possible to represent the circle as a single entity?

Comment: Take a look at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/q/3874424/5241603. Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was very helpful! I am creating a custom drawable class to control the complexity :)